# If user already exists in wp_users table of wordpress db?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am having problem when I try to cross check that user name from one wordpress database is exists in another wordpress database or not. If its exist return me `true` but if it isn't then return `false`. Right now its showing all false.

Here is my code

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name");

foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo $row->user_login;
    if ( in_array("$row->user_login", $results2, true)  ){
        echo " <span>(True)</span><br>";
    }
    else{
        echo " <span>(False)</span><br>";
    }
}
```

Second database query

```
$results2 = $seconddb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name");
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  It isn't clear how your calling this, and whether you can actually echo output, or which tables you're querying.

Answer (score 0):

**Method A:**

Does you $tablename also include `$wpdb->prefix`?

eg.

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'users';
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $table_name );
```

Also you are checking inside an array of objects. You should first get the array of usernames.

```
// Transform array of user objects to usernames array.
$results2_usernames = array_map( function( $row ) {
    return $row->user_login;
}, $results2 );
```

So your new check will be:

```
if ( in_array( $row->user_login, $results2_usernames ) ) {
   // Return true
} else {
   // Return false
}
```

**Method B:**

This is similar but it could run faster if you have a lot of users.

First you need to adjust your results query and return only `user_login`:

```
    $table_name  = $wpdb->prefix . 'users';

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `user_login` FROM " . $table_name );
```

This still returns an array of objects but it is a lot smaller. We can use `wp_list_pluck()` to transform it to an array of usernames':

```
$results_usernames = wp_list_pluck( $results, 'user_login' );
```

If you print the above array you might see something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => john-doe
    [1] => jane-doe
...
)
```

Complete code:

```
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `user_login` FROM " . $table_name );
    $results_usernames = wp_list_pluck( $results, 'user_login' );
    $results2_usernames = wp_list_pluck( $results2, 'user_login' );

    foreach ( $results_usernames as $username ) {
        echo $username;
        if ( in_array( $username, $results2_usernames ) ) {
            echo " <span>(True)</span><br>";
        }
        else{
            echo " <span>(False)</span><br>";
        }
    }
```